# Windows Server 2012 - Distributed Scan Server service won't start

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I just purchased a printer/scanner (Epson WF-7620) and am trying to configure it as a network printer/scanner for the first time. I have it connected to my server computer via a USB printer cable. I installed all of the print management roles but the scan server role/feature won't start. Printing works fine through the network. I can get on a desktop and see the printer that's on the server and print to it. I can also use the scanner but I have to be on the server to do it. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to allow me to use the scanner to scan documents and have the server place the scanned documents into a shared folder on the network. Any ideas?

I'm assuming the problem is because the scan server service won't start but I can't figure out how to get it to do so to safe my life. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not configure the server with SMTP (point that to your eMail server) and then it can do "scan 2 email" as explained by Epson [here](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd4/cpd41349/source/printers/source/networking/tasks/wfr5690_4640/setting_up_email_server_wfr5690.html).